# Read/write memory mapped boost::ptr_vector?

Tags: c++, memory, serialization, boost

I have a large `boost::ptr_vector` whose content I need to read from disk at runtime.

Currently I'm using a `boost::serialization` binary archive to write and read the `ptr_vector`. Would reading from disk at runtime be faster if I used a memory mapped file with `boost::interprocess`?

If so, does anyone have a mini example that shows how to do this?

Comment: There is a strong semantic difference between the two: `ptr_vector` owns its elements (one by one), whereas in the case of `mmap` you would have a single large chunk of memory and several pointers within that area. Also, note that in the case of `mmap` you would only be able to store POD (Plain Old Data) and pointers would have to be replaced by offsets from some origin. TL;DR: `mmap` is probably faster, but the data-structures are different and probably less intuitive.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks, makes sense. If my data structure were just a `vector` of data chunks, where each data chunk may have a different size -- could I then use a memory map? Or would all data chunks in the `vector` have to be of the same size?

Comment: You could not be using a `vector<Chunk>` (the vector would not own the memory). If you use a `Chunk*` (array of chunks), then they all have to have the same size, if you use a `vector<Chunk*>` then each can have a different size (in practice) though I would remind you than in theory `sizeof(Chunk)` is fixed and only C allows tail-padding (that is, the last member being a `<type> X[];`).

Comment: Thanks. I just don't understand how I would write and read a `vector<Chunk*>` as memory mapped file. I'll open a new question for this.

Comment: It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531243/how-to-read-write-vectorchunk-as-memory-mapped-files